# pages.zip file will fail to displays view using UIWebview and NSURL

Tags: objective-c, uiwebview, nsurl

I have an application that displays search tips.  This will work if I store an .html file in the main bundle and display it using the Apple example code:

```
-(void)loadDocument:(NSString*)documentName inView:(UIWebView*)webView
{
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:documentName ofType:nil];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [webView loadRequest:request];
}

//load document --
    [self loadDocument:@"searchTipsLegislators.html" inView:searchTips];
```

If however I change the document to one created using a compressed Pages file the app return the error:

> 2010-12-15 08:53:04.537 cv112[42067:7003] Cannot load iWorkImport
>
> 2010-12-15 08:53:04.538 cv112[42067:7003] Failed to generate preview

Has anyone gotten this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things to try:

1. Don't compress the pages document. This is no longer necessary as of iOS 3.
2. Don't expect this to work on Simulator. Does it work on your device?

Comment: Thanks,  will try this the next time.  I switched to an html file instead.